# Pass information from a dying application to a respawning itself

Tags: linux, windows, startup, exit

Platform: Windows + Linux

I have an application running on Linux and Windows (written in Qt). This application does some operations, calculates some values, and suddenly it realizes that it needs to exit due to various circumstances (maybe a signal handler kicked in). This application was started from a batch (shell on linux) script which automatically restarts it when it detects that the application exited.

The problem is that it does not want to lose all the calculations it did because it would take a long time to re-do them. The other problem is that this calculation is highly sensitive information so it does not want to write it to any file on the filesystem (someone might see it) or registry, nor does it want to upload it somewhere (maybe there is someone watching the network).

SO here comes the problem: How does an application that is about to exit pass information to the same application which will be started after the current application exited? Is this even possible?

Comment: Maybe put the data in a shared memory segment, with appropriate permissions.

Comment: "The other problem is that this calculation is highly sensitive information so it does not want to write it to any file" - swap is also a file.